# Must I do 26 times mysql query in a directory list page group by A-Z?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to make a directory list page for my site. The page show all my site articles. And these articles groupe by the title's first letter.

Must I run 26 times mysql query like

```
mysql query like "SELECT * FROM articles Where title like 'a%'"
mysql query like "SELECT * FROM articles Where title like 'b%'"
mysql query like "SELECT * FROM articles Where title like 'c%'"
...
mysql query like "SELECT * FROM articles Where title like 'z%'"
```

And My html output are:

```
<div class="content">
   <p>A</p>
   <a href="somelink">Anhui</a>
   <a href="somelink">Aomen</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
   <p>B</p>
   <a href="somelink">Beijing</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
   <p>C</p>
   <a href="somelink">Chongqing</a>
</div>
...
<div class="content">
   <p>Z</p>
   <a href="somelink">Zhejiang</a>
</div>
```

So is there any good advise that I shall do less mysql query and get the same result? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply do SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY title, then test for a change to the first character of title in the for loop where you're reading the resultset?

Comment: @Mark Baker: for my stupid, I still not guess the way to cut `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` in one foreach...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Make a single query, and order them alphabetically, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY title ASC
```

Then, as you loop through them to show them, keep track of the last article you showed. If the first letter of the current article is different than the last's, put your separation.

```
$prevFirstLetter = '';
while($data = nextResult()) {
    $firstLetter = substr($data['title'], 0, 1);
    if ($firstLetter != $prevFirstLetter)
        echo "<h1>$firstLetter</h1>";
    echo "{$data['title']}<br>";
    $prevFirstLetter = $firstLetter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please tell me you've tried

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `title`
```

Then when you're looping, track the first letter (accessible by using `$string[0]`) if it changes, create the new content div.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through this query

```
SELECT *,LEFT(title,1) FirstLetter FROM articles ORDER BY title ASC
```

Check for the FirstLetter Column

Just write `<a href="somelink">' . $title . </a>` over and over again until FirstLetter Switches From 'A' to 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

I would run one query, have it return them to you in sorted order, and then split them up once they're in code. Seems silly to do 26 queries when 1 will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could select everything, in one query, and order by title name. Then, in your PHP code, you need some logic to break over the recordset whenever you encounter a change in the first letter.